# MSYS2 - Change to /bin/sh

Tags: bash, sh, msys2

How would I switch my default shell from bash to sh in MSYS2?  Even just trying to do something as simple as `pacman -S sh` tries to install bash.

Comment: Please show output of `type chsh`.

Comment: ...$ chsh
bash: chsh: command not found  

...$ type chsh
bash: type: chsh: not found